# Using Swift .split to format an array

Tags: swift, string

I am reading in a text file of translation pairs of this format:

boy:garçon

garçon:boy

Into an array using the following code:

```
  var vocab:[String:String] = [:]
    
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "words_alpha", ofType: "txt")!
    let text = try! String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let vocab =  text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
```

The imported array looks like this:

["boy:garçon", "garçon:boy"]

Whereas I would like the array to be formatted like this:

["boy":"garçon", "garçon":"boy"]

What is the best way to achieve the desired array format shown above using a Swift string transformation?

Have been trying to use .split, but with not much success.

Comment: "Whereas I would like the array to be formatted like this:" You want a dictionary then?

Comment: `let dict = text.split(whereSeparator: \.isNewline).map({$0.components(separatedBy: .punctuationCharacters)}).reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.first ?? ""] = $1.last }`

Comment: Note that it would be much better to start with a json instead of text not properly formatted. `let text = #"{"boy":"garçon","garçon":"boy"}"#`. Then you can simply decode it using JSONDecoder `let dict = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: String].self, from: Data(text.utf8))`

Comment: Thank you for the quick feedback. Worked like a charm, although I had to clean up a trailing space after the colon in the dict data by adding this Swift string replace function:                                                                                                           let cleanup = text.replacingOccurrences(of: ": ", with: ":")

Answer (score -1):

Let's be clear:

```
["boy":"garçon", "garçon":"boy"]
```

That's a Dictionary, not an Array.

There a multiples ways to do that, here's two possible codes:

```
var manual: [String: String] = [:]
array.forEach { aString in
    let components = aString.components(separatedBy: ":")
    guard components.count == 2 else { return }
    manual[components[0]] = components[1]
}
print(manual)
```

or

```
let reduced = array.reduce(into: [String: String]()) { result, current in
    let components = current.components(separatedBy: ":")
    guard components.count == 2 else { return }
    result[components[0]] = components[1]
}
print(reduced)
```

Output (for both):

```
$> ["garçon": "boy", "boy": "garçon"]
```

As said, it's a Dictionary, so there is no guarantee that the print be:
`["garçon": "boy", "boy": "garçon"]` or `["boy":"garçon", "garçon":"boy"]`, it's key-value access, not index-value access.